# If a homeomorphism between two metric spaces and its inverse are uniformly continuous, do we have "X is bounded implies Y is bounded"?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $(X,d_X)$, $(Y,d_Y)$ be metric spaces, $\phi:X\to Y$ be a homeomorphism.
>
> Assume $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ are uniformly continuous.
>
> Prove or disprove:
>
> If $X$ is bounded, then $Y$ is bounded.

Any advice or comment is greatly appreciated.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: If we are trying to prove boundedness then it is false and there are easy counterexamples. For total boundedness it is true. Which is it?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake (I mixed it up with another problem). It's boundedness, not totally boundedness. Are there counterexples? Could you indicate a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a counterexample take any space with an unbounded metric, give it a bounded metric, and use the identity map. For example, $(\mathbb R,|\cdot-\cdot|)$ is unbounded and $(\mathbb R,d)$ is bounded, where 
$$d(x,y)=\min(1,|x-y|)$$
and the identity map is uniformly continuous, as is its inverse (which is also the identity map).

Comment: Thank you. I see it was actually an easy problem.

Comment: @Alice no problem.